# Multiple authenticationProvider in Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

Is it possible to define multiple `authenticationProviders` in Micronaut?

Let's say I have an **entity A** which can be logged using **authenticationProviderA**: which given a user and pass checks the **DB table of A**.

Is it possible to add an **entity B** and its **authenticationProviderB** which given a user and pass will check the **DB table of B**?
If so, how do you define in your controller which `authenticationProvider` you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at `io.micronaut.security.authentication.Authenticator` I've seen it's possible to have multiple `authenticationProviders` in Micronaut.

The documentation says:

> An Authenticator operates on several `{@link AuthenticationProvider}` instances returning the first authenticated `{@link AuthenticationResponse}`.

From what I've seen you just have to implement `AuthenticationProvider` and the `Authenticator` will include the implementations (even if it isn't annotated!) in an internal list of `AuthenticationProviders`.

IMHO this isn't a good way to provide multiple ways to authenticate. In the example provided in the question, the authentication for A and B both require calls to DB which means depending on the order of the execution of the `AuthenticationProviders` unneeded BD calls will be executed.

I think would be better to provide a way to indicate which `AuthenticationProviders` has to be used by controller or endpoint. 
Maybe there is a way to do that and I just don't know, so feel free to comment if so.

Comment: You can simply return empty in any authentication provider that should not be used to authenticate a given user

Comment: " will include the implementations (even if it isn't annotated!) " That isn't true. Any classes injected into the Authenticator must be beans.

Comment: How do you know which authentication should be used given the credentials? in other frameworks the auth provided to use is defined by path. With Micronaut you only have the credentials to determine which auth provider to use, am I right? If so, I don't see how you can determine the auth provider to be used. 
About the inclusion of the implementation I will test again, just in case.

Comment: You're right about "any class injected must be beans" when I've executed the tests from command line (with mvn) without the @Singleton annotation the authentication provider was missing. The behavior from the IDE is different for some reason that I still don't know, because when debugging with IntelliJ I've checked the constructor is called even without annotation

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution regarding the problem, but there are multiple ways to achieve what you want with small amount of code.

**Solution №1**:
Creating custom `AuthenticationRequest.class` and `LoginController.class` if you need multiple login end points:

`public class AuthenticationRequestForEntityA extends UsernamePasswordCredentials { ... }`

`public class AuthenticationRequestForEntityB extends UsernamePasswordCredentials { ... }`

in your custom `LoginController` replace the default `UsernamePasswordCredentials` with your specific `AuthenticationRequestForEntityA` or `AuthenticationRequestForEntityB` and copy paste the rest of the code from the original `LoginController.class`:

```
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Post
    public Single<MutableHttpResponse<?>> login(@Valid @Body AuthenticationRequestForEntityA usernamePasswordCredentials, HttpRequest<?> request) {
        Flowable<AuthenticationResponse> authenticationResponseFlowable = Flowable.fromPublisher(authenticator.authenticate(request, usernamePasswordCredentials));
        ...
```

and then in your authentication providers:

```
public class AuthenticationProviderA implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@Nullable HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, AuthenticationRequest<?, ?> authenticationRequest) {

       if (authenticationRequest instanceof AuthenticationRequestForEntityA) {
           return authenticate(authenticationRequest);
       } else {
           // return empty
       }
    }

}
```

```
public class AuthenticationProviderB implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@Nullable HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, AuthenticationRequest<?, ?> authenticationRequest) {

       if (authenticationRequest instanceof AuthenticationRequestForEntityB) {
           return authenticate(authenticationRequest);
       } else {
           // return empty
       }
    }

}
```

**Solution №2**: Creating your custom route-based `AuthenticationProvider`

Since `HttpRequest` is available in the `AuthenticationProvider` as an input parameter you can simply authenticate based on the `httpRequest` path or query parameter properties.
To make the code cleaner you can create your own `RouteBasedAuthenticationProvider` interface:

```
public interface RequestBasedAuthenticationProvider extends AuthenticationProvider {
  
  /**
    You can check the request path or request parameter or whatever
  */
  boolean supports(HttpRequest<?> request);
}
```

then in Micronaut `AuthenticationProvider`:

```
@Context
public class AppAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final Collection<RequestBasedAuthenticationProvider> providers;

    constructor(...) {...} 

    @Override
    public Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@Nullable HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, AuthenticationRequest<?, ?> authenticationRequest) {

       return providers.stream()
           .filter(provider -> provider.supports(httpRequest))
           .findFirst()
           .orElseThrow(//Throw provider not found error)
           .authenticate(httpRequest, authenticationRequest);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't test it, however I've chosen a different framework which solves the problem in a much "developer friendly" way: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/auth.html#chained-factories